# mingw g++ is unable to link with libraries

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, cross-platform

I'm trying to use `X86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` (packaged in Archlinux's MingW package) to cross compile some C++ code into an Windows executable, however I'm having trouble getting past some issues.

I'm calling

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o build_win/asm build_win/asm.o build_win/asm_lib.o build_win/socket_boost.o -I../extra/etc -fopenmp -lrt -std=c++11 -g -lboost_system -lboost_serialization
```

from a makefile, but I get thrown the errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lrt
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_serialization
```

This works fine with native g++, so exactly do I have to change for mingw to compile?

EDIT: I have `mingw-w64-boost` package installed, which includes boost libraries pre-compiled and ready to be linked. However, it seems the naming convention is a bit different, and `-lboost_system` for example becomes `-llibboost_system-mt` (not exactly sure what the -mt suffix entails).

Problem is I can't find the mingw counterpart for `-lrt`. I've tried with both `-lrtm` and `-lrtutils` but in both cases I get:

```
[...] 
undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `-lboost_system` and other libraries are present in the same directory as makefile ?

If `not` then please include `-L` flag which indicates the location of your library.

For example:

```
-L /path_openmp -fopenmp -L /path_boost_system/ -lboost_system -L /path_serialization -lboost_serialization
```

Moreover, you need not include `-I` and `-g` flag when creating an executable from `.o` files. These are needed when you create `.o` from `.cpp` files.

Comment: Indeed they are not. But it works with native `g++`, so I though those flags pointed the linker towards the system's libraries. Now that I think about it, mingw requires their own version of boost (need to find them though)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `rt` library on Windows.

You are missing `-lws2_32`.

```
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm -A  /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/*.a 2>/dev/null | grep getsockopt | grep " T "
```